# How do I turn off Percy snapshots for branches and most ember-try scenarios?

Tags: ember.js, travis-ci

I am using Percy in the tests for an Ember Addon, but the Percy snapshots run 12 times for every pushed commit. I only want them to run for Pull Requests and the main version of my addon.

Here is why they run 12 times right now:
- Once for every ember try scenario (6 times)
- This is repeated for both PRs and branches pushed to GitHub

I am using Travis CI. How do I cut down the number of times that Percy snapshots run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `travis.yml`, you can set the Percy token as an empty string ENV variable for each scenario you want to skip:

```
- stage: "Additional Tests"
  env: EMBER_TRY_SCENARIO=ember-lts-3.4 PERCY_TOKEN=""
- env: EMBER_TRY_SCENARIO=ember-lts-3.8 PERCY_TOKEN=""
- env: EMBER_TRY_SCENARIO=ember-release PERCY_TOKEN=""
- env: EMBER_TRY_SCENARIO=ember-beta PERCY_TOKEN=""
- env: EMBER_TRY_SCENARIO=ember-canary PERCY_TOKEN=""
```

If your config allows any failures, be sure to add the Percy token there too so the scenario matches. For example:

```
  allow_failures:
    - env: EMBER_TRY_SCENARIO=ember-lts-3.4 PERCY_TOKEN=""
```

Travis provides an environment variable `TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST` that you can check and set the `PERCY_TOKEN` conditionally. This can be done in many different places in a Travis file, so here's one example:

```
before_install:
  - 'if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" = "false" ]; then PERCY_TOKEN=""; fi'
```

See the docs for [Conditionals in Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/).

Thanks to tbieniek for the help in the community chat, and SO user jrjohnson for the tip that setting the PERCY_TOKEN to and empty string is the best approach.

Comment: I'd suggest a small tweak to this. Setting `PERCY_TOKEN="skip percy"` still ends up sending API queries to percy.io. An empty string of `PERCY_TOKEN=""` disables the tests without sending an API request that is intended to fail.